# With libxml, how to get the character position of a given element or attribute in the source xml file?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

With libxml2, we can use `xmlGetLineNo` to get the line number in which a node appears in the source XML file.

But how to get character positions of **a given element** and **a given attribute**? I need both the `start` and `end` positions in the source xml file for both a node and an attribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SAX2 interface which has the [xmlSAX2GetColumnNumber](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-SAX2.html#xmlSAX2GetColumnNumber) method.

Comment: Sorry, I traveled in the past weeks. I'll go back to this topic soon.